# Determining whether something occurs when an element is clicked

Tags: javascript

Does anybody have ideas on a foolproof method of determining whether something happens (a javascript event, or in the simple case, an  tag), when a DOM element is clicked?

What are some possibilities of things to check for? For example, you could check for an `<a>` tag, an `onclick` event, etc.

In more complex cases, Javascript might simply detect where the click falls on the page and take action depending on that (i.e. the event is not associated with an element, but the whole page, and when the click occurs, it checks which element it falls on).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a direct answer but [VisualEvent](https://github.com/DataTables/VisualEvent) is a JS library that inspects a multitude of event handlers, both native and library-attached handlers. It's opensource so you can see how they did it.